# How to shield Android 4.0 HOME Key

Tags: java, android

Does anybody know how to shield the HOME key in Android 4.0?

The code below only works in 2.2 and 2.3, so how would I change this so it can work in 4.0?

```
/* FIXME:  How does it works within Android 4.0? */
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        //do nothing  
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It's not an edit to your code, but it's an alternative work around for the same purpose.